# HTML loop based on php value

Tags: php, html

I have a php/html page, 
In the php I am pulling data out of a sql table which works fine no problem

```
<?PHP
    $data = <Get SQL Data>
?>
```

Below I have the Html section where I display a gannt chart

```
<?PHP
    $data = <Get SQL Data>
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">

<!-- Head -->
    <head>
        Head Stuff
    </head>

    <!-- Demo -->
    <div>
    <div id="embedded-Gantt">
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var g = new JSGantt.GanttChart(document.getElementById('embedded-Gantt'), 'week');
      g.setCaptionType('Complete'); (None,Caption,Resource,Duration,Complete)


      <Need To Add Data to gannt chart here>


      g.Draw();
      </script>        
    </div>
  </div>
```

In the above code, the section

```
<Need To Add Data to gannt chart here>
```

I need to add the data to chart by calling

```
g.AddTaskItem(new JSGantt.TaskItem(1,   'App',     '',           '',          'ggroupblack',  '',                 0, 'User',    0,     1,      0,       1,     '',      '',      'Some Notes text', g ));
```

What I don't know though is how to loop the above line of code for each $data (from php) loop. Or is there a better way of doing this?

Im a embedded developer and this is my first venture in PHP/HTML

Thanks

Comment: You can loop from php or just call `json_decode()` and output it as json string then loop from javascript

Comment: JSGant demands XML input, therefore JSON is useless; besides the instruction would otherwise be `json_encode()` ...better use XHR to load XML; rendering `foreach` `g.AddTaskItem(new JSGantt.TaskItem( ... ));` is crappy.

Comment: for example http://jsgantt.com/jsgantt_exExternalXML.html ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guesting $data is an array, you can do it with a foreach

```
<div id="embedded-Gantt">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var g = new JSGantt.GanttChart(document.getElementById('embedded-Gantt'), 'week');
  g.setCaptionType('Complete'); (None,Caption,Resource,Duration,Complete)

  <?php
  foreach($data as $item) {
      ?>
      g.AddTaskItem(new JSGantt.TaskItem(<?php echo $item['id']?>,   '<?php echo $item['name']?> ........));
  <?php
  }?>


  g.Draw();
  </script>        
</div>
```

If you are using another way to complete the $data, share the complete code.
Look the TaskItem parameters, the item represent each row, sow fill all parameters with the sql column names, and pay attention if the data is a string or number, like id or name, because you need the quotes.
Good luck